# Checking which radio button is clicked everytime and validating - php

Tags: javascript, php, html, validation, radio-button

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($retval))
{

  $c0=$row['c1'];
  $c1=$row['c2'];
  $c2=$row['c3'];
  $c3=$row['c4'];
  $id=$row['id'];
  $v1=1;
  $v2=2;
  $v3=3;
  $v4=4;
  echo "{$row['qn']}  <br> ";
  echo "<input type=\"Radio\" name=\"$id\" value=\"$v1\">"."$c0<br>";
  echo "<input type=\"Radio\" name=\"$id\" value=\"$v2\">"."$c1<br>";
  echo "<input type=\"Radio\" name=\"$id\" value=\"$v3\">"."$c2<br>";
  echo "<input type=\"Radio\" name=\"$id\" value=\"$v4\">"."$c3<br>";

  echo     "--------------------------------<br>";          
}
```

This is my code to display questions from the DB and its choices for my quiz application.

Here, at least to my knowledge the name for each radio group is the 'number' of the question as id is auto incremented sequence in my application. On client side how to check which radio button is clicked?  I tried something like `$_POST['radiogroupname']` in `isSet()` but that doesn't work either and i don't know how to do so since all my radio group names are numbers only and i couldn't even get the result with looping in the client side for the `$_POST['Parameter']`.

How to fix this?

Comment: `name` cannot start with digit. Renaming buttons to smth like `name=\"rb_$id\"` will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks! I Used \"r_$id\" in 'name' and in the client side i tried to echo if (isset($_POST["r_$id"])) {
  echo $_POST["r_$id"];
} inside loop for ($id to some number) but nothing worked! Can you help me?